# How can I Training my data set which composed only True? in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am a beginner in python and I'm studying machine learning in python using tensorflow.

I have two data set 'trainset.csv' 'testset.csv'

trainset.csv like(just example):

```
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 normal  abnormal
---------------------------------
 0 1 2 3 1 2 1 4 6   1        0
 0 1 1 1 4 1 1 2 1   1        0
 0 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2   1        0
 ...
 0 1 1 1 1 4 3 1 1   1        0
```

tesetset.csv like(just example):

```
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
--------------------
 0 1 2 1 3 4 1 4 5  
 0 1 1 1 4 5 5 5 5 
 0 2 3 1 5 2 1 2 2 
 ...
 0 1 6 1 7 4 3 4 1
```

How can I train my train set data which only presented normal feature and classify abnormal data in test set?

Comment: Either you are missing *abnormal examples* in you training data and you have to get them in order to train something, or your problem is not classification but *outlier detection*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need abnormal training examples, or else the network will learn to output "normal" every single time. If you want to do anomaly detection with no anomalies in the training set, I'm not sure a neural network is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) library here because it's quite convenient to use with data. Concerning your problem - I think you have to create new train dataset from all possible combinations of values and then train on that.

Let's say you have a dictionary with all possible values for all columns. I fake it here by getting all possible combinations from your train dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> del df['abnormal']
>>> cols = [x for x in df.columns if x != 'normal']
>>> cols
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> d = df[cols].apply(lambda x: list(x.unique())).to_dict()
>>> d
{'1': [0], '3': [2, 1], '2': [1, 2], '5': [1, 4], '4': [3, 1], '7': [1, 3], '6': [2, 1, 4], '9': [6, 1, 2], '8': [4, 2, 1]}
```

Then you can create full dataframe from this:

```
>>> df_full = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(*d.values())), columns=d.keys())
```

And now you can create new train dataframe:

```
>>> df_train_new = pd.merge(df_full, df, how='left').fillna(0)
```

So it will have all possible combinations of values + filled `normal` column